# Convert VBA select case to C#

Tags: c#, vba, select-case

```
Select Case True
 Case Not A.Name Is Nothing
   Set Name = A.Name
 Case Not A.Age Is Nothing
   Set Age = A.Age
 Case Not A.School Is Nothing
   Set School = A.School
End Select
```

In VB `Select Case True` is allowed to use. But for C# it gives an error. How can I convert this  VB code to C# ?

Comment: I'll add the comment here: The problem with your select idea is that you will always ONLY update one of the variables instead of checking each of these. As soon as one of them is true, rest of the case statements will be ignored. Like @Eric said, use IF/ELSE statements

Comment: @Jawad that's the requirement. Here I added only a sample code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct analog in C# because C# case labels must be constant expressions. `Select Case True` is an unusual construct that serves as an alternative to `if-else` constructs.

I suggest replacing it with the far more common pattern:

```
if (A.Name != null)
    Name = A.Name;
if (A.Age != null)
    Age = A.Age;
// ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using switch case in c# is some different. I think this example can be able to useful to you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      var values = new List<object>();
      for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 7; ctr++) {
         if (ctr == 2)
            values.Add(DiceLibrary.Roll2());
         else if (ctr == 4)
            values.Add(DiceLibrary.Pass());
         else
            values.Add(DiceLibrary.Roll());
      }

      Console.WriteLine($"The sum of { values.Count } die is { DiceLibrary.DiceSum(values) }");
   }
}

public static class DiceLibrary
{
   // Random number generator to simulate dice rolls.
   static Random rnd = new Random();

   // Roll a single die.
   public static int Roll()
   {
      return rnd.Next(1, 7);
   }

   // Roll two dice.
   public static List<object> Roll2()
   {
      var rolls = new List<object>();
      rolls.Add(Roll());
      rolls.Add(Roll());
      return rolls;
   }

   // Calculate the sum of n dice rolls.
   public static int DiceSum(IEnumerable<object> values)
   {
      var sum = 0;
      foreach (var item in values)
      {
            switch (item)
            {
               // A single zero value.
               case 0:
                  break;
               // A single value.
               case int val:
                  sum += val;
                  break;
               // A non-empty collection.
               case IEnumerable<object> subList when subList.Any():
                  sum += DiceSum(subList);
                  break;
               // An empty collection.
               case IEnumerable<object> subList:
                  break;
               //  A null reference.
               case null:
                  break;
               // A value that is neither an integer nor a collection.
               default:
                  throw new InvalidOperationException("unknown item type");
            }
      }
      return sum;
   }

   public static object Pass()
   {
      if (rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0)
         return null;
      else
         return new List<object>();
   }
}
```

You can give more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) about switch case

Answer (score 0):

Your VBA code mimics an `If-Then-ElseIf ...` block, so how about:

```cs
if (A.Name != null)
{
    Name = A.Name;
}
else if (A.Age != null)
{
    Age = A.Age;    
}
else if (A.School != null)
{
    School = A.School;
}
```